# Cloudinary: Class cloudder not found in production, works fine locally

Tags: laravel-5, cloudinary

I am using this cloudinary package https://github.com/jrm2k6/cloudder on my laravel 5.4 project, it works fine on the local machine but throws an error called class cloudder not found in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A

```
composer dump-autoload
```

should fix it.